# Memory leak example

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

Explain please step by step a reason of memory leak in the following part of code:

```
var theThing = null;
var replaceThing = function () {
  var priorThing = theThing;  // hold on to the prior thing
  var unused = function () {
    // 'unused' is the only place where 'priorThing' is referenced,
    // but 'unused' never gets invoked
    if (priorThing) {
      console.log("hi");
    }
  };
  theThing = {
    longStr: new Array(1000000).join('*'),  // create a 1MB object
    someMethod: function () {
      console.log(12);
    }
  };
};
setInterval(replaceThing, 10);
```

Comment: What makes you think there's a memory leak?

Comment: I tried your code in Chrome and indeed the RAM inscreases very fast until the webpage crashes at around 650MB of RAM

Comment: I don't know about a leak but "new Array(1000000).join('*')" is very expensive, it will give you a million (-1) *'s (why you need this I don't know)

Comment: Year but the thing i have to know they RAM increases each 10 ms.
The part of code is just example from memory leak theme.